# RPM и установка антивируса Kaspersky

Tags: centos7, rpm, kaspersky

Хочу установить антивирус касперского на CentOS. Скачал с сайта kesl-10.1.0-5960.x86_64.rpm файл. Следуя инструкции выполняю с правами рута команду

> `# rpm -i kesl-10.1.0-<номер сборки>.i386.rpm`

на что мне консоль отвечает

> `ошибка: распаковка архива не удалась на файле /var/opt/kaspersky/kesl/install/opt/kaspersky/kesl/bin/kesl-control;5c01142e: cpio: read не удалось - Нет такого файла или каталога
>   ошибка: kesl-10.1.0-5960.x86_64: установить failed`

Я распаковал архив руками и нашел этот файл в указанной директории. Система CentOS 7. Кто знает в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Тянешь wget'ом отсюда https://support.kaspersky.com/kes10linux#downloads

1. For Linux (rpm) x64: Distributive: kesl-10.0.0-3458.x86_64.rpm [26.0 MB]
2. For Linux (rpm): Network Agеnt: klnagent-10.1.1-26.i386.rpm [6.3 MB]

   sudo -i

Ставишь скаченное через `yum install`.